# Robotic arm calibration

Tags: computer-vision

I'm working on an image recognition software for bacteria colony. So far I have been able to obtain the pixel coordinates of the colony recognized. Now what conversion operation should I apply so that a robot arm can pick up the colonies? any suggestions on what I should look up? A little clueless here

Answer (score 0):

"Camera calibration" (intrinsic and extrinsic) yields the geometric relationship between pixels on the image and rays in 3D space.

"Hand-eye calibration" relates the kinematics (direct and inverse) of a robotic arm to the geometry of a camera observing the robot's workspace.

There are vast amounts of literature on both subjects, hard to be more specific without knowing more about your particular use case.